# using fileexists to check file on network pc - php

Tags: php, iis

I'm trying to use fileexists to check if a file exists on a network server.

It keeps coming back with false and I think this is probably to do with permissions, as it seems to work from localhost and not the webserver I'm running it from.

I've tried to log the World Wide Web Publishing on as a network admin, but when restart the service I get the error message

Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: the file I'm trying to see if exists is : \\Scanserver\osw\PurchaseOrders\Output\0000C0D5\0000C0D5_0016.tif

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on http://serverfault.com . They should be better suited to tell you anything you need to know about the "entanglement" of the www, ftp, iis admin, ... services and how to use impersonation to run your script on a different account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer just permissions setting as thought:

Go into the Properties for the IIS web-site, Directory Security tab.
Edit anonymous access and authentication
Edit the account used for anonymous access
Select a network login account with the required privileges

sorted